# Is Firefox the only browser that supports not reloading all open tabs at startup?

Tags: windows, web-browser, firefox

I always set my browser to reopen all tabs from the previous session, but of course I don't want the browser to also *load the content* of each tab, I want it to load only the content of the active tab, and load the other tabs only if and when I switch to them.

The main reason why I want that is that one or more of the tabs can contain a video or a stream, which I obviously want to start only when I switch to that tab; I don't want all the tabs containing videos to start playing their videos simultaneously at startup.

The only browser I know that implements this trivial and obviously needed (in my opinion) feature is Firefox.
IE does not seem to me to support this feature.
Opera does not support this feature and from my research on their forum there are several users waiting for this since years. The exact same thing goes for Chrome. I am really surprised about that.

Up until now I used Firefox, but since a while Firefox started crashing and completely freezing my Windows 8.1 computer, so I'm looking for another browser that supports saving the tabs from last session but not reloading their content at startup.

ADDED: I was able to stick to Firefox thanks to a suggestion from the comments below that allowed me to eliminate the reason why I was looking for another browser: `disabling hardware acceleration under Settings>Advanced` made FF stop making my video driver crash.

Comment: See here http://superuser.com/questions/811965/how-to-make-chrome-not-load-tabs-until-they-are-selected

Comment: @SantiBailors Try deleting your Firefox profile, uninstalling Firefox, rebooting, and then reinstalling Firefox.  Firefox is used by hundreds of millions of people, so it is likely a temporary problem with your installation or profile.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Thanks, I don't know where my Firefox profile is - or what it is - but when I have time I will try to find out and give it a shot. I'm not optimist, because I know those FF freezes have to do with my video driver (NVIDIA GeForce GT 640, v. 9.18.13.2702) which according to control panel is up to date; that driver tends to crash and then the display gets weird. If at that point FF is open it might crash or not but it always results in a very deep freeze where not even Caps Lock responds; not sure which one is causing the other but when I use other browsers no freezes.

Comment: @MatthewLock Thanks, I'm still baffled that all major browsers except FF don't have this basic feature (which I'm sure would be absolutely trivial for them to implement) and that workarounds or external plugins are needed, but that's clearly the case so I will take into account the options described in your link.

Comment: @SantiBailors Make sure you also try disabling hardware acceleration under Settings>Advanced.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard That is one great suggestion, I'm going to try that right away. HW acceleration was actually on. I can't +1 now due to reputation but thanks a lot and I will update this to report how it went.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Your suggestion solved my problems, I no longer had any crash after I disabled HW acceleration, and that means I can keep using FF which is great news for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @SantiBailors That's great!  I'm glad that worked!  Thanks for letting us all know.  :)

Comment: @SantiBailors Would you add your experience as an answer to this question for future visitors? (Comments can be deleted anytime, so they are not a good store for answers)

Comment: @AngeloFuchs OK, I just edited my question and added the solution. I hadn't posted it as an answer earlier because although the problem that prompted me to look for another browser and thus ask the question has been solved, technically there isn't an answer to the question itself here, so I had just written my experience in a comment; but I had no idea that comments are at higher risk of being deleted; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SantiBailors: You wrote "I'm looking for **another** browser" (bold emphasis mine). -- The [tag:firefox] tag should be used on questions that look for software that works/interacts with Firefox (like extensions). If we’d keep the [tag:firefox] tag on this question, people browsing for answers wouldn’t find solutions that work with Firefox (like the already recommended browser Midori), and that wouldn’t be helpful.

Comment: Really @unor ? You deleted my latest comments ? Including the one where I replied to your comment and I explained why I thought the "firefox" tag was useful ? Were those comments offensive ? Contained fabricated information ? Contained obscenity ? Didn't know how to respond ? Do you feel better now ?

Comment: @SantiBailors: I can’t delete your comments.

Answer (score 2):

[Midori](http://www.midori-browser.org/) is a lightweight browser who also supports this feature by the normal settings menu.

Comment: Midori is an excellent browser, but it is not currently available for Windows 8.1, which is the OS for which SantiBailors requested a recommendation.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Doesn't it? [This page](http://midori-browser.org/download/portable/) claims that it “should work on all Windows systems”.

Comment: @Gilles According to [the current Midori FAQ](http://midori-browser.org/faqs/) "Releases exist on various Linux distributions, for Windows versions prior to 8.1 (for now), and BSD", yet according to [the page you found](http://midori-browser.org/download/portable/) "Midori Portable should work on all Windows systems".  Obviously, one of those statements is in error, and I do not know which one.  Perhaps someone can inquire with Midori or try it on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Looks like it functions just fine for me on 8.1 x86; clean install, nothing tweaked, no errors, loads pages and so forth.